# How to create String of length consisting of same character repeated multiple times?

Tags: java

If i want a `String s` which would consist of `n` instances of character `A`, can this be done cleaner in Java other then

```
public static String stringOfSize(int size, char ch) {
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    while (size-- > 0) {
        s.append(ch);
    }
    return s.toString();
}
```

Can we do better? Just wondering.

Comment: It would be cleaner if you didn't change the parameter variable, but otherwise it looks good to me.

Comment: You should presize your builder.  (or just use a `char[]`)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Nothing wrong with this code at all... But maybe you can use `Arrays.fill()`:

```
public static String stringOfSize(int size, char ch)
{
    final char[] array = new char[size];
    Arrays.fill(array, ch);
    return new String(array);
}
```

Comment: I think that this option is the best. To increase speed (but consume more memory) we can also add caching to this solution. Store results in `Map<Integer, Map<Character, String>> cache` and then just get right string without generation.

Answer (score 7):

You could do the following:

```
return StringUtils.repeat(ch, size);
```

Note: `StringUtils` is not built-in to the JDK - see http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/

Comment: There is no builtin `StringUtils` in the JDK.

Comment: Or just `StringUtils#repeat()` if `StringUtils` is available.

Comment: @fge - you are right, added a note

Comment: @Keppil - thanks, that's much nicer