# Can't assign char "X" in part of String

Tags: java, string

I can't assign a specific char like "X" in part of my input string.
For example I want to assign a default char with substring method in specific range of my input string. How can I assign a specific char in specific range of my
input string.

Can you help me?

```
import java.util.*;
public class Algoproject {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
         while(true){
        int num=input.nextInt();//number of colums
         if(num!=0)    {  
         String s;
         s=input.next();//enter string without space
        int count=s.length();//string length
         displayMessage(s,num,count);
         }else
             break;    
         }

    }
    public static void displayMessage(String str, int pi,int slength){
      int j=0,i=pi;
      while(pi<=slength){

                System.out.print(str.substring(j,pi )+"\n"); 
                j=pi;
                pi=pi+i;
    }
      System.out.print(str.substring(j,slength )); 
      String in="$";
      //line29
    }}
```

in line 29 I want a method that give 3 value:

1. my arbitrary char
2. first index of my string
3. last index of my string

and I want to assign that char in this string range

Comment: Unclear what you are asking for.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please visit the [help] and read [ask].  Your question is unclear, and you need to show us the code you are working with.  Otherwise it is considered off-topic.

Comment: Java *and* C? Which language are you using?

Comment: i use java and i want method to assign arbitrary char in a specific range of my input string

Comment: `str = str.substring(<pick the first part of the string>) + stringOfSize(lengthToInsert, 'X') + str.substring(<pick the end of the string>)`.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/16800351/646887 for an example on how stringOfSize could be constrructed.

Answer (score 0):

Get the index at which you want to assign your character, suppose it's "x"
Then do this

```
newstring = originalstring.substring(0, x) + your_character + originalstring.substring(x, originalstring.length());
```