# repeat string n times in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I want to create a `string` which would contain a `*` symbol `n` times.
I only see this way:

```
val s = ""
val n = 100
for (j in 0 until n) {
    s += "*"
}
```

But it looks ugly and it has a O(n^2) time complexity. Is there a way in Kotlin to do that without a loop with better time complexity?

Comment: This is actually O(n²) because `s += "*"` recreates the whole string (length 1 to n) with one more "*" added.

Comment: I corrected the question, thanks

Comment: To solve the performance problem use `val s = StringBuilder(n)`

Answer (score 86, accepted):

The built in [`CharSequence.repeat`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/repeat.html) extension does this in an efficient way, see the source [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.2.0/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/text/StringsJVM.kt#L409).

```
val str: String = "*".repeat(100)
```

Of course, this will still require O(n) steps to create the string. However, using this built-in stdlib function has its advantages: it's cross-platform, easy to read, and can be improved in performance over time, if there's a more efficient solution. The loop inside it will probably be optimized by the compiler or the runtime anyway.

Comment: Looks good, thanks! Seems like there is no way to do it faster then O(n), what do you think?

Comment: If you look at the same question for Java ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2804827/4465208) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16800295/4465208) for example) everything seems to involve looping through the length of the string / array once.

Comment: @Rainmaker There is no way to add n strings together in less than O(n). You will always need to visit each string at least once.

Answer (score 6):

You can overload the `*` operator to map it to the existing [repeat extension](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/repeat.html):

```
public operator fun CharSequence.times(count: Int): String {
    return repeat(count)
}

fun main() {
    val s = "*" * 101
    println(s)
    println("Badger " * 12 + "Mushroom " * 2)
    println(s)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

An alternative to the CharSequence.repeat is a CharArray with an init function:

```
CharArray(N, {i -> '*'}).joinToString(separator="")
```

This solution has the advantage that you can define prefix, postfix, and separator.

Comment: Kotlin 1.4 introduced [`CharArray.concatToString()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/concat-to-string.html), so if you don't need the extras from `joinToString()` you can also do `CharArray(10) { '*' }.concatToString()`

Answer (score 5):

If you need a separator, this initializer function from List is helpful:

```
val str: String = List(100) { "*" }.joinToString(",")
```

Answer (score 3):

`StringBuilder` would improve the [memory footprint here](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/stringbuilder-and-kotlin/441/2):

```
val sb = StringBuilder() 
val n = 100
for (j in 0 until n) {
  sb.append("*") 
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's better, thanks, but it's still loop and still O(n)

Comment: O(n) is better than the original O(n^2), tho

Comment: Why n^2? There is only one loop

Comment: strings are immutable, hence the n^2 to copy the result on each concatenation.

Comment: You don't have to instantiate the StringBuilder, do it like this instead:    
       val result = buildString { (0..100).forEach { append("*") } }

Comment: @Rainmaker you can't beat O(n) for repeating a string `n` times, but the point about the loop is true. Still, this is a welcome addition to the accepted answer as a generalization.

Comment: I thought that starting from Java 1.8 concatenation of strings is done using StringBuilder internally.
Not sure if it applies to Kotlin case though (especially in case of JavaScript Kotlin flavour).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Anton Sizikov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48446386/) and https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/repeat.html, we can write:

```
val sb = StringBuilder().apply{
    repeat(100) {
        append("*")
    }
}
```

But this is a simple way. Look at a [power](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26689929/power-function-using-recursion) function. It has O(log n) complexity.

For `StringBuilder`:

```
private fun power(sb: StringBuilder, n: Int): StringBuilder =
    when {
        n == 0 -> StringBuilder("")
        n % 2 == 0 -> {
            val part = power(sb, n / 2)
            part.append(part)
        }
        else -> {
            val part = power(sb, n / 2)
            part.append(part).append(sb)
        }
    }
```

For `String`:

```
private fun pow(s: String, n: Int): String =
    when {
        n == 0 -> ""
        n % 2 == 0 -> pow(s, n / 2).repeat(2)
        else -> s + pow(s, n / 2).repeat(2)
    }
```

Then we can invoke them:

```
// 1.
val sb1 = StringBuilder().apply {
    repeat(100) {
        append("*")
    }
}

// 2.
val sb2 = power(StringBuilder("*"), 100)

// 3.
val s = power("*", 100)

println(sb1.toString())
println(s)
println(sb2.toString())
```